# Reparameterization invariance of strings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

I'm working through Zweibach's First Course In String Theory.

I'm stuck on a problem (16.1) where I need to show that the coupling Kalb-Ramond field to a worldsheet have the following transformation:

$$\int d\tau' d\sigma' \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial \tau'} \frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial \sigma'} B_{\mu \nu}(X) = {\rm sgn}(\gamma) \int d\tau d\sigma \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial \sigma} B_{\mu \nu}(X)$$

where ${\rm sgn}(x)$ is the sign of $x$; and $\gamma = \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial \tau'} \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \sigma'} - \frac{\partial\tau}{\partial \sigma '}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \tau '}$; and the reparameterization of the world sheet coordinates go from $(\tau, \sigma)$ to $(\tau'(\tau,\sigma),\sigma'(\tau,\sigma)))$.

I don't have any particular conceptual questions, but I do have a lot of things I've tried. I'm confused about when things are vectors and when they are not in this problem.

1. gamma is the same as the Jacobian in a change of variables, which is similar  (maybe inverse?) as the square root of the determinant of the metric (of what?).
2. $\gamma$ and what I've been calling$\gamma^{-1}$ where  $\gamma^{-1} = \frac{\partial \tau'}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial \sigma'}{\partial \sigma} - \frac{\partial\tau'}{\partial \sigma }\frac{\partial \sigma'}{\partial \tau }$ are not quite multiplicative inverses of each other unless the cross terms are zero (Or if the gammas were vectors and I took the dot product).
3. I can find the total derivatives for $d\tau'$ , $d\sigma'$, and the velocities, and multiply them together, but then I end up with something like $\gamma*\gamma^{-1}*$ (the unprimed coupling), plus a number of extra terms which all go to zero if $\frac{\partial \tau'}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial \tau'}{\partial \sigma}=0$. This seems reasonable since the vectors along tau and sigma are perpendicular.
4. It seems like, algebraically, the only way for sgn(gamma) to appear in an equation would be to have$(\sqrt{{\rm sgn}(\gamma)*\gamma})^2*\gamma^{-1}$ where the sign was installed to ensure that the sign under the square root was positive.

Could someone help me piece these observations together?

Comment: Note: Earlier I had assumed that the whole thing must be symmetric so the $\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial \sigma} $this is trivial, since the whole thing is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking this. Note that it's crucial that $B$ is antisymmetric. If it were a symmetric tensor, you wouldn't have a transformation law of that form.

Edit: OK, here is the spiel. I'll write $\sigma^i = (\tau,\sigma)$ and $\sigma'^i = (\tau',\sigma')$ to make the expressions more compact. First note that the integral measure transforms as

$$\int d^2 \sigma' = \int d^2 \sigma \, |\det(\partial \sigma'^i/\partial \sigma^j)|.$$

Next, we consider how the partial derivatives transform. Notice that we can use the antisymmetry to write

$$B_{\mu \nu} \frac{\partial X^{[\mu}}{\partial \tau'} \frac{\partial X^{\nu]}}{\partial \sigma'} = \frac{1}{2}B_{\mu \nu} \frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial \sigma} \left[ \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial \tau'}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \sigma'} - \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial \sigma'}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \tau'}\right] = \frac{1}{2}B_{\mu \nu} \frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial \tau} \frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial \sigma} \det(\partial \sigma^i/\partial \sigma'^j).$$

To conclude, you only need to realize that 
$$ |\det(\partial \sigma'^i/\partial \sigma^j)| \det(\partial \sigma^i/\partial \sigma'^j) = \pm 1$$
depending on the sign on the determinant.

Comment: Hm. So since B is antisymmetric, and the entire thing is a scalar, then $\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial \tau'}\frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial \sigma'}$ is also antisymmetric. I was already considering this. Am I missing another effect of an antisymmetric B?

Comment: Dear pongoS, do you still need an answer? I missed your comment the first time around.

Comment: I was never able to figure out this problem so an answer would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I just made an edit to explain this. Just writing this so you will be notified.